# How to listen to child components?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jcomponent, mouselistener

I have a `JPanel` with a grid of `JLabels` added. I'd like a `MouseListener` to listen for `MouseEvents`, but the `JLabels` seem to be in the way and no `MouseEvent` fires when clicking in the location where a `JLabel` is located.

Is there a relient way to listen to the `MouseEvents` of a component's children?

Comment: Can the parent add itself as a listener whenever a component is added?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MouseEvents are dispatched to the top-most (in z-order) component that is enabled for them, that has a mouseListener registered on it or internally has set the eventMask to handle them. While typically a JLabel is transparent (and thus the events should reach the underlying panel), they might get event-opaque by f.i. setting a tooltip.

In jdk 7, you can [use a JLayer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#events) to get hold of all (mouse) events delivered to its children. The documentation of `JLayer` says:

> JLayer is a good solution if you only need to do custom painting over
>   compound component **or catch input events from its subcomponents**.

It's predecessor for jdk6 is the [JXLayer project](http://jxlayer.java.net) in SwingLabs. Yet another option is to use an AWTEventListener, as described in [Rob's blog](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) (beware: might not be allowed in security restricted contexts)

Comment: Thank you very much for the well-explained answer. I do have tool tips on each of the JLabels, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Definitely the best and most to the point answer on this topic - thanks.